# XSLT help to concatinate nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need help with XSLT which should conctainte same field from different node. To be clear below is my xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CustomReport">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:payGroup wd:Descriptor="Pay1">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f6ab553ac49b10f860xxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">Pay2</wd:ID>
        </wd:payGroup>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:payGroup wd:Descriptor="Pay2">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f6ab553ac49b10f860xxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">Pay2</wd:ID>
        </wd:payGroup>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:payGroup wd:Descriptor="Pay3">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f6ab553ac49b10f820xxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">Pay3</wd:ID>
        </wd:payGroup>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I am expecting this below output with feilds being concatinated with commas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File 
   <RECORD>
      <Paygroups>Pay1, Pay2, Pay3</Paygroups>
   </RECORD>
</File>
```

I tried below xslt beut I am not able to get commas in between values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CustomReport"
  
     
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">       
        
        <File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"  xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">          
            
            <RECORD>     
                <Paygroups>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:payGroup/@wd:Descriptor"/>
                </Paygroups>
            </RECORD>
        </File>                                         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting below without commas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
      xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">
   <RECORD>
      <Paygroups>Pay1 Pay2 Pay3</Paygroups>
   </RECORD>
</File>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to indicate the separator that you want as an attribute of the `value-of` element as in:

```
<value-of separator="," ... />
```

The separator by default for a sequence is the space character. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-value-of

The following modification of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CustomReport" 
    version="2.0" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">       
        <File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"  xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">          
            <RECORD>     
                <Paygroups>
                    <xsl:value-of separator="," select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:payGroup/@wd:Descriptor"/>
                </Paygroups>
            </RECORD>
        </File>                                         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CustomReport" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xtt:separator="&#13;&#10;">
   <RECORD>
      <Paygroups>Pay1,Pay2,Pay3</Paygroups>
   </RECORD>
</File>
```